# How to update Google chrome in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, updates

How to update Google chrome in Ubuntu?

Comment: @Ignacio: Add/Remove Applications and it's not there.

Comment: This helped me install the lasted Google Chrome on Ubuntu via command line: https://askubuntu.com/a/510063/48214

Answer (score 120):

First download and install the key from [Google Linux Repository](http://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/). Or run the following commands in the terminal, type the password for the user when prompted.

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
sudo apt-get update
```

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-beta
```

To update only:

```
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install google-chrome-stable
```

Then update (if available) the Network Security Service libraries (libnss), or Chrome will behave [weird](https://askubuntu.com/questions/880695/neterr-cert-weak-signature-algorithm-error-for-google-chrome-stable-version/881199#881199)

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3-1d
```

> In Ubuntu 18.04 or later *libnss3-1d - Network Security Service
>   libraries - transitional package* is depreciated and incorporated in
>   generic *libnss3* library. (*Thanks Bishoy Melek*)
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install libnss3
> ```

Now you have to kill all instances (may be hidden) of old Google Chrome.

```
sudo pkill -15 google-chrome
sudo pkill -15 chrome
```

Then start google-chrome as you start it.

Comment: Thanks. `killall google-chrome` works well also.

Comment: Says `google-chrome-stable is in the latest version available`. But I'm on Chrome 30.0.1599.101 and apparently version 32 exists now. Is the debian package regularly updated as well?

Comment: No, Debian packages are NOT regularly updated. And this depends on your Ubuntu version.

Comment: There is a simpler way to restart Chrome. Just open this link - chrome://restart . Source - https://plus.google.com/+FrancoisBeaufort/posts/VVv36sA79Mu.

Comment: @IliaBarahovski .. Yeah. You can. But I'll prefer the bash line approach, it's the unix way of life :)

Comment: worked for me Ubuntu 14.10
{[9303:9339:0915/095009.401468:FATAL:nss_util.cc(632)] NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.}

Comment: sudo pkill -15 google-chrome
sudo pkill -15 chrome;          Execute this command and then open chrome@AugustinRiedinger

Comment: Not working in my case. I have ubuntu 18.04. And the version of google chrome is 70.0.3538.77-1. It's not getting upgraded following all these steps. Getting this E: Repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' changed its 'Origin' value from 'Google, Inc.' to 'Google LLC'
when i did "sudo apt-get update"

Comment: This worked https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-google-chrome-web-browser-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: Why install `google-chrome-beta` instead of google-chrome-stable`? `libnss3` is installed as a dependency.

Comment: Worked as a charm

Comment: Is this outdated?

Comment: @dimitri-kopriwa I just used the `apt-key add... ` instructions to solve the problem of chrome not updating.  All the other generic instructions I had gone through previously failed to get the job done.  So I'd say that part is not outdated.  But I didn't need anything else (eg libnss3).

Answer (score 17):

From the [Chrome EULA page](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?platform=linux&hl=en):

> **Note:** Installing Google Chrome will **add the Google repository** so your system will automatically keep Google Chrome up to date. If you don't want Google's repository, do "sudo touch /etc/default/google-chrome" before installing the package.

[emphasis theirs]

So, as **mgpyone** indicated Ubuntu's [`update-manager`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/en/man8/update-manager.8.html) should take care of that for you.

Here are the contents of my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/ stable main
```

Answer (score 6):

If it does not update properly, just download the last `.deb` file from:
https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/

The deb file like `google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

Then you can:

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Replace `/path/to` with your proper path.

It just worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: simple and awesome.

Answer (score 3):

From [Google Chrome Help](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95414)

> Use your package manager to check for
>   updates.
>
> Privacy information
>
> Google Chrome uses a process called
>   Google Update to periodically check
>   for updates. This process sends
>   information, such as version number,
>   language, operating system, and other
>   installation or update-related
>   details, back to Google servers. This
>   information is not associated with you
>   or your Google Account.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with broken package in Chrome 20.0.xxx. I could see two chrome packages in Synaptic package manager. I deleted the new version of chrome package then marked older version on chrome package for upgrade. Then upgrade all packages through, which took care of everything and my Chrome was upgraded to the latest version.